# Clear Pickle `memo` in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I am building a `Server-Client` model using Socket programming in Python 2.7.
For sending the data(strings and File both) i am using `Pickle` module.Here is the error i am getting in the mid-way of the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 30, in <module>
     C1_pick = pickle.loads(data_ciphertext)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
     return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
     dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1162, in load_binget
     self.append(self.memo[repr(i)])
  KeyError: '101'
```

When I use the **pickle.dumps()** and **pickle.loads()** for the first time, it is working fine, but after that i am getting this error.
Searching on the Python Doc of Pickle module I learnt that the `Pickle memo` needs to be cleared.
Unfortunately, using:

```
 mypickler.memo.clear()
```

shows a `NameError`.
I want to know how to clear the Pickle memo for Python2.7(exact commands)?

Comment: I think you can search python documentation.

Comment: I have seen that, i need the exact line of code.BTW, i am not creating an instance.I am just calling the function.

Comment: What's `data_ciphertex` source?

Comment: @PedroLobito the server machine is sending the ciphertext(C1) (for now it is on the same machine)

Comment: The `memo` is used by an `Unpickler`, not by `Pickler` (as with `mypickler.memo`); that is why you get a `NameError`. Since you are using `loads()`, you are also using a transient instance of `Unpickler`; clearing it's `memo` won't get you anywhere. I'd suggest you try setting `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` to some lower value during `dumps` or use `pickletools.dis` to take a look at the disassembly of the pickle opcode stream.

Comment: @user2722968 How will setting HIGHEST_PROTOCOL to lower change the working?

Comment: There is no memo to clear, because a *new, fresh `Unpickler` instance is created each time you call `pickle.loads()`.* You need to share an [mcve] here that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The exception indicates your pickle stream is invalid. The `memo` object is used as a mapping to store references to objects already unpickled. The error is thrown because a `MEMOIZE` ocde is missing or the reference number is incorrect.

Comment: This is probably related to how you handle your files, so post your code.